# cgps: GPS timeout error with BU-353 USB GPS Receiver

Tags: gps

I have bought myself a  BU-353 USB GPS Receiver and trying to use it with the Pi,

I have followed this tutorial to set it up,

> This is how we were able to install and run the GlobalSat BU-353 GPS
>   module on our Raspberry Pi
>
> From the command prompt, type:
>
> sudo bash
>
> apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps
>
> nano /lib/udev/gpsd.hotplug
>
> Scroll down the document and add chmod a+rw $DEVNAME above the line
>   that says gpsdctl $ACTION $DEVNAME
>
> Press CTRL and O together to save
>
> Press CTRL and X together to exit the file
>
> /etc/init.d/gpsd restart
>
> gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
>
> cgps -s
>
> You will now see the GPS output

But when I am writing `cgps -s` an empty table shows up with each value equals to `n/a`.

What is wrong here ? Could anyone please help me. ?

It merits mentioning that I am using puTTy to access my Raspberry Pi and have done all above steps using puTTy.

Answer (score 1):

there might be a few instances of gpsd running at the same time you're unaware of.

kill 'em all and restart gpsd:

```
sudo killall gpsd
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your GPS unit is as close to a window as possible. If you're in the middle of your house/office, it won't get a signal and will say n/a indefinitely.

I have the same unit hooked up to my pi and it works fine in my office but not in a center office in my building.